# From a data set, print a new set with some conditions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of 16 vectors ($P[i]$), where $i=0,15$. Among them few are equal. I want to print all $P[i]$'s such that they are not same. Like $P[0]=\{0,1,2,1,0\}$, $P[1]=\{0,1,0,0,0\}$ and $P[2]=\{0,1,2,1,0\}$. Here I want to print $\{0,1,2,1,0\}$ and $\{0,1,0,0,0\}$ as $P[0]$ and $P[2]$ are equal.

Comment: "All are different": do you mean delete the duplicate elements? (e.g. `{1,1,2}` becomes `{1, 2}`) Then try `DeleteDuplicates[list]`. Do you mean take elements that appear only once? (e.g. `{1,1,2}` becomes `{2}`) Then try `Cases[Tally[list], {a_, 1} :> a]`

Comment: Have you read [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html)?

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 2, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}} // DeleteDuplicates
```

**Output**

> {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 2, 0, 1}}

**Reference**

[DeleteDuplicates](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html)